# CheckBox Checked property not updating while form is running

Tags: c#, forms, checkbox

I have a simple function that returns whether a checkbox is checked or not, and another method from another class uses this info.

Whenever I change the "Checked" property to false before running the form, my code works as expected and treats the boolean variable for the checked property as false. However, if i try to change the checkbox while the form is actually running, my code always treats the checked property as true regardless of whether the box is checked or not.

My code is not a Form1_Load one time thing, it is a function that is called every time a button is clicked. (Of course this button was clicked after the checkbox was untoggled, and it still treats the checkbox checked variable as true even though it should be false.)

Literally my code:

(I understand this looks like a weird way to check it, but it's needed because of class to class referencing issues)

```
    public bool Check1()
    {
        check1 = this.checkBox1.Checked;
        return check1;
    }
```

Check1(); always returns true regardless of whether checkBox1 is checked or not. But again, if I uncheck the checkbox prior to running the form, it returns false as it should.

Any suggestions to get it to update properly?

EDIT:

```
                Block_Map_Array.Form1 f = new Block_Map_Array.Form1();
```

It is called in the new instance.

Comment: Is this WPF, WinForms, MVC or WebForms?

Comment: Could you provide the full interaction, or assignment, with/of `check1` ? Could it be getting set somewhere else?

Comment: Nee more details before we can help

Comment: Can this be tied to the CheckBox.OnCheckedChanged Method?  From there have it run Check1() ?

Comment: You say, *"another method from another class uses this info"*. We need to see the code that calls this method. it's possible you're loading up a new instance of the `Form1` class to call this method, rather than using the instance of the form displaying the UI.

Comment: The assignment is just assigning bool check1; the variable is retrieved by another method but is never set anywhere else besides this one.

Comment: if (generated[i, j] == 1 && f.Check1() == true)

Comment: (f is an object reference to the form class where Check1() is contained)

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my question. Where is `f` defined? Is it a **new** instance of the form, or is it passed into the other class from the original instance? (edit your question and show the code, please, not in comments)

Comment: Well, then that is the problem. You are not dealing with the same instance of the form that is being displayed. You need to pass the form instance to the other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this in your form class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool check1;

    public bool Check1()
    {
        check1 = this.checkBox1.Checked;
        return check1;
    }

    // rest of class omitted
}
```

And you want some other class to have access to this instance method of the UI form, you will need to provide a way for the form to pass itself to your other class, for example:

```
class Block_Map_Array
{
    private Form1 f;

    public Block_Map_Array(Form1 uiInstance)
    {
        this.f = uiInstance;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        if (f.Check1())
        {
            // do something...
        }
    }

    // rest of class omitted...
}
```

Then, when you instantiate this class from `form1`, you could do something like:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Block_Map_Array foo = new Block_Map_Array(this);

    foo.SomeMethod();
}
```

Of course, this is not really the best design. Normally you would pass some data directly to the method from the form, rather than the whole form instance.

Comment: Yep, just had to pass the form instance to the class. The checkbox now updates properly.